# How find number of instances for 3rd party class org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer

Tags: java, jvm

I have a web app, it is using third party libraries that are using jboss dispatcher.
Sometimes it goes out of resources because of some internal problems. Because it is third party, I can't control how it works or fix any bugs there.

I need to detect this situation. I know that app need to be restarted if there are many instances of org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer. I need to count the instances of that class. Please note that I can't modify HashedWheelTimer, add instance counters or do something like this. Also I can't modify classes that are using HashedWheelTimer as well.

Seems like My only option is to count number of instances.

How can I count number of instances for class org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer?

Can I do this with Garbage Collector or may be JVM tools?
[image]